# How to convert list to dataframe without type conversion on date

Tags: r, date, dataframe, types

I'm trying to write a script which can take a file, look up some metadata of relating to the file, and convert certain columns based on that metadata. For example, suppose my data looks like the output of the following:

```
test_data <- data.frame(date1 = c("03/02/2018","04/25/2018"),date2 = c("9/14/17","9/27/17"))
```

and suppose that, based on a metadata lookup I found that the columns `date1` and `date2` of the input file have, respectively, the formats

```
date_formats <- c("%m/%d/%Y","%m/%d/%y")
```

So my script would then proceed to define `index` as a boolean vector which contains the value `TRUE` where I have a date column and `FALSE` otherwise, and then attempt to convert all such columns to a standardized R date format:

```
test_data[,index] <- as.data.frame( 
                     lapply(test_data[,index],as.Date,
                     format = date_formats[index],
                               origin ="1970-01-01")))
```

But this produces some bizarre output:

```
  date1      date2
1 2018-03-02 0017-09-14
2 2020-04-25 2017-09-27
```

Notice that the years for the (1,2) and (2,1) entries are off. I don't understand why the other values were properly converted. That is mystery #1.

The other mystery is that, if I try to convert only one column, say

```
as.data.frame(lapply(test_data[,1],as.Date,format = c("%m/%d/%Y")))
```

then I get undesirable output:

```
structure.17592..class....Date.. structure.17646..class....Date..
1                       2018-03-02                       2018-04-25
```

and if I first wrap this with `cbind` a la

```
as.data.frame( cbind(lapply(test_data[,1],as.Date,format = c("%m/%d/%Y"))))
```

then what I get are the raw, unformatted date values because of the behaviour of `cbind`:

```
    V1
1 17592
2 17646
```

So how can I write this generic method which can handle an arbitrary number of columns, with different formats, and convert them all to the same formatted date type in a dataframe?

Comment: Some newer read-in functions like those from [readr](https://readr.tidyverse.org/) can parse dates while reading data and thus prevent this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
test_data <- data.frame(date1 = c("03/02/2018","04/25/2018"),date2 = c("9/14/17","9/27/17"))
date_formats <- c("%m/%d/%Y","%m/%d/%y")
index <- c(TRUE,TRUE)

test_data[,index] <- 
  as.data.frame( 
    lapply(which(index),function(i) 
      as.Date(test_data[[i]],
              format = date_formats[i],
              origin ="1970-01-01")))

#        date1      date2
# 1 2018-03-02 2017-09-14
# 2 2018-04-25 2017-09-27
```

The `index` you were feeding to `date_formats` in your lapply loop was always of length 2, lapply didn't loop on it. We need to convert your boolean index to numeric, and then loop on it.

Here is cleaner code to achieve what you want:

```
test_data[,index] <- 
  Map(as.Date,test_data[index],date_formats[index],origin ="1970-01-01")
#        date1      date2
# 1 2018-03-02 2017-09-14
# 2 2018-04-25 2017-09-27
```

Comment: This appears to work quite well, thanks! I wasn't aware of the Map function, looks handy :)

Comment: When you find yourself looping on an index with `lapply` in order to use this index in several vectors or lists, it's often time to think about `Map` or `mapply`. See also `map2`, `pmap`, `imap` from `purrr` package

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Perhaps `origin ="1970-01-01"` argument is not needed as data is `character` format and `format` argument has been specified.

Answer (score 1):

It seems OP's intention is to read the data from a file, certain columns of which contain date in different formats. `@Moody_Mudskipper` has already provided a nice solution to convert data once it has been read from file.

Another option is to use `colClasses` argument of the read functions(i.e. `read.table`, `read.csv` etc.) itself and get the date columns converted.

```
# Test data to be read from file. I have added one more column ID in data from OP
textData <- "
ID       date1   date2
1 03/02/2018 9/14/17
2 04/25/2018 9/27/17"

setClass("dateformat1")
setClass("dateformat2")

setAs("character", "dateformat1", function(from)as.Date(from, format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
setAs("character", "dateformat2", function(from)as.Date(from, format = "%m/%d/%y"))


read.table(text = textData, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
           colClasses = c("numeric", "dateformat1","dateformat2"))

#   ID      date1      date2
# 1  1 2018-03-02 2017-09-14
# 2  2 2018-04-25 2017-09-27
```